# How can I retrieve an HTML form value and put it in a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, forms, axios

so I'm kind of a beginner at JavaScript and APIs, things like that. I want to implement an API into my website that can detect whether an article is fake news or not based on the title. I already found the API, [which is this](https://rapidapi.com/fangyiyu/api/fake-news-detection1), but I'm a bit confused with how to retrieve the form value from my HTML code, shown below:

```
<input type="text" name="check" id="check">
    <button onClick="checkFakeNews" id="btn">Check</button>

    <p id="result"></p>
```

I already tried typing up this function:

```
function checkFakeNews() {
    document.getElementById('check') = text
    console.log(text)
}
```

to try to print out the value, but I didn't get anything.

I also want to get the result, stored in 'data' in the API I believe, and display it in the paragraph. I'd be very grateful to anyone who can help me!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You are you writing `document.getElementById('check') = text` which doesn't do anything.

Second thing that in HTML `onClick` need to be equal to Function Call you are passing just the Name. You need `checkFakeNews()` instead of `checkFakeNews`

This should work as required.

```js
function checkFakeNews() {
  const input = document.getElementById('check');
  const text = check.value;
  console.log(text);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="check" id="check">
<button onClick="checkFakeNews()" id="btn">Check</button>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Hi I'm so sorry to bother you, but if i may ask a further question do you know how to get this in a variable? I'm trying to assign a value to const.params.text but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: In my code, you can see I have assigned the value to variable text. Can you clarify what exactly is this `const.params.text`?

Comment: in the API, the text value for params

Answer (score -1):

https://www.javatpoint.com/document-getElementById()-method , and see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp

var s = document.getElementById("element").innerHTML; //to set

document.getElementById("myText").value = "Johnny Bravo"; to set